# What fraction of a Pawn do the most powerful chess engines (Komodo, Stockfish, Houdini, Fritz, Hiarcs, Gull, ...) use as their evaluation unit?

Tags: engines, stockfish, programming, point-value, fritz

I've heard that the most common evaluation unit is 1/100 of a Pawn. But some engines use 1/1000 of a Pawn as their evaluation unit.

I've also heard that Stockfish used 1/256 of a Pawn as its evaluation unit (although it was 5 years ago, maybe it has changed today).

So what about the strongest and best-know chess engines: Komodo, Houdini, Fritz, Hiarcs, Gull, etc... what evaluation unit do they use?

Answer (score 2):

Chess engines use centi-pawns.

https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Centipawns

Comment: Worth noting that all engines (at least those supporting the UCI protocol or similar) report their scores in centipawns in order to comply, but that doesn't _necessarily_ mean that they don't compute lines internally with greater precision.

Comment: It's pointless to compute with greater precision. All engines use integer. Look at the Stockfish source code and you will see that I'm correct.

Comment: I agree that Stockfish does, but it's not inconceivable that some other engine could find a use for that precision. As mentioned above, an earlier version of Stockfish used 1/256.

Comment: Which engine uses that? Houdini? Komodo?